# Make formulas start at the same point

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, enumerate

I would like to list a few formulas which I have done as following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Hommes and in 't Veld AR(1) model:}
    \begin{align}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}(n_{1,t} \phi_1 + n_{2,t}\phi_2)x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t.
    \end{align}
\item \textbf{Weak trend following AR(2) model:}
    \begin{align}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + 1.4n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - 0.4n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{align}
\item \textbf{Strong trend following AR(2) model:}
    \begin{align}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + 2.3n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - 1.3n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{align}
\item \textbf{General trend following AR(2) model:}
    \begin{align}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + (1+\phi_3)n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - \phi_3n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I would like to let these `x_t` begin at the same point. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of `amsmath`'s `\intertext`. By default this will not allow page breaks within the `align` environment, but if necessary it can be made possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Hommes and in 't Veld AR(1) model:}
    \begin{align}
        x_t &= \frac{1}{R^*}(n_{1,t} \phi_1 + n_{2,t}\phi_2)x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t.\\
\intertext{\item \textbf{Weak trend following AR(2) model:}}
        x_t &= \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + 1.4n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - 0.4n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.\\
\intertext{\item \textbf{Strong trend following AR(2) model:}}
        x_t &= \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + 2.3n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - 1.3n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.\\
\intertext{\item \textbf{General trend following AR(2) model:}}
        x_t &= \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + (1+\phi_3)n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - \phi_3n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example you can also use `aligned` where I have defined the `\Indent` macro to allow you to control the indentation:

[image]

### Notes:

- As hooy commented, With this method you do not get the equation numbers.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\Indent}{\par\hspace*{1.0cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Hommes and in 't Veld AR(1) model:}
    \Indent$\begin{aligned}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}(n_{1,t} \phi_1 + n_{2,t}\phi_2)x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t.
    \end{aligned}$
\item \textbf{Weak trend following AR(2) model:}
    \Indent$\begin{aligned}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + 1.4n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - 0.4n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{aligned}$
\item \textbf{Strong trend following AR(2) model:}
    \Indent$\begin{aligned}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + 2.3n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - 1.3n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{aligned}$
\item \textbf{General trend following AR(2) model:}
    \Indent$\begin{aligned}
        x_t = \frac{1}{R^*}((n_{1,t} \phi_1 + (1+\phi_3)n_{2,t})x_{t-1} - \phi_3n_{2,t}x_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t.
    \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One will lose the equation numbers, though, if they are necessary.

Comment: @hooyL Good point... Have made a note of that,